# Как в SQLAlchmey добавить свое поле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Мне надо  в выборку добавить свое значение. Написал так:

```
is_flag = False

...query(...,
         (is_flag).label('flag)',
         ...)...
```

Но не дает так:

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'label'

Дополнение:

Грубо говоря, как реализовать такой запрос в SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT
     id, 
     10 as 'number'
FROM
     TableDB;
```

Comment: Какой должен получиться результат? Куда именно должно добавиться это значение?

Comment: @insolor, в кортеж выборок. Т.е. в выборке должно появится дополнительное поле "flag", со значением *is_flag **

Comment: Если средствами Python - можно просто в модель добавить поле, по умолчанию равное нужному значению, не делая это поле колонкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-общем я решил эту проблему следующим образом (не знаю на сколько она удачна):

```
is_flag = 1 if is_flag else 0     # тут логическое значение привожу к бинарному (1/0)
```

в выборке умножаю

```
...query(...,
         (dbTable.id * is_flag ).label('is_flag')', 
         ...)..
```

И потом обратно получаю свой результат в нужном месте.

```
data_is_flag = True if elements_rows.is_flag > 0 else False
```